# Update node on server running multiple apps

Tags: node.js, pm2

I got an Ubuntu 18 server running multiple node apps, unfortunately I did not install node using `nvm`.

All of the apps are running with `pm2` and are currently `online`. One of the apps I just finished requires a higher version from the current `v15.3.0` I got installed on the server.

What would be the best strategy to update node so it fixes this app but does not break the others?

Comment: Why not use Docker? Containerization would solves this exact issue without any conflicts between apps

Comment: I have not done so, is it a lot of work to incorporate `Docker` to a set up that's runing without it?

Comment: That depends on the app, there are lots of great tutorials for beginners. Ultimately it's worth it to avoid having to struggle with versioning and cross platform comparability